# How to pass in the model name during init in Azure Machine Learning Service?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am deploying 50 NLP models on Azure Container Instances via the Azure Machine Learning service. All 50 models are quite similar and have the same input/output format with just the model implementation changing slightly.

I want to write a generic score.py entry file and pass in the model name as a parameter. The interface method signature does not allow a parameter in the init() method of score.py, so I moved the model loading into the run method. I am assuming the init() method gets run once whereas Run(data) will get executed on every invocation, so this is possibly not ideal (the models are 1 gig in size)

So how can I pass in some value to the init() method of my container to tell it what model to load?

Here is my current, working code:

```
def init():

def loadModel(model_name):
    model_path = Model.get_model_path(model_name)  
    return fasttext.load_model(model_path)

def run(raw_data):
    # extract model_name from raw_data omitted...
    model = loadModel(model_name)

    ...
```

but this is what I would like to do (which breaks the interface)

```
def init(model_name):
    model = loadModel(model_name)

def loadModel(model_name):
    model_path = Model.get_model_path(model_name)  
    return fasttext.load_model(model_path)

def run(raw_data):
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to use the same deployed container and switch models between requests; it's not the preferred design choice for Azure machine learning service, we need to specify the model name to load during build/deploy.

Ideally, each deployed web-service endpoint should allow inference of one model only; with the model name defined before the container the image starts building/deploying.

It is mandatory that the entry script has both `init()` and `run(raw_data)` with those **exact** signatures.

At the moment, we can't change the signature of `init()` method to take a parameter like in `init(model_name)`.

The only dynamic user input you'd ever get to pass into this web-service is via `run(raw_data)` method. As you have tried, given the size of your model passing it via run is not feasible.

`init()` is run first and only **once** after your web-service deploy. Even if `init()` took the `model_name` parameter, there isn't a straight forward way to call this method directly and pass your desired model name.

---

But, one possible solution is:

You can create params file like below and store the file in azure blob storage.

Example runtime parameters generation script:

```py
import pickle

params = {'model_name': 'YOUR_MODEL_NAME_TO_USE'}

with open('runtime_params.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(params, file)
```

You'll need to use [Azure Storage Python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python) to write code that can read from your blob storage account. This also mentioned in the official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-deploy-and-where#prepare-to-deploy).

Then you can access this from `init()` function in your score script.

Example `score.py` script:

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
import pickle

def init():

  global model

  block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(connection_string='your_connection_string')

  blob_item = block_blob_service.get_blob_to_bytes('your-container-name','runtime_params.pkl')

  params = pickle.load(blob_item.content)

  model = loadModel(params['model_name'])
```

You can store connection strings in Azure KeyVault for secure access. Azure ML Workspaces comes with built-in KeyVault integration. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.keyvault.keyvault?view=azure-ml-py#get-secret-name-).

With this approach, you're abstracting runtime params config to another cloud location rather than the container itself. So you wouldn't need to re-build the image or deploy the web-service again. Simply restarting the container will work.

---

If you're looking to simply re-use `score.py` (not changing code) for **multiple model deployments in multiple containers** then here's another possible solution.

You can define your model name to use in web-service in a text file and read it in score.py. You'll need to pass this text file as a dependency when setting up the image config.

This would, however, need multiple params files for each container deployment.

Passing 'runtime_params.pkl' in `dependencies` to your image config (More detail example [here](https://github.com/rithinch/heartfulness-similar-content-service/blob/master/experiments/notebooks/Deploy%20Model%20-%20Azure.ipynb)):

```py
image_config = ContainerImage.image_configuration(execution_script="score.py", 
                                                  runtime="python", 
                                                  conda_file="myenv.yml",
                                                  dependencies=["runtime_params.pkl"],
                                                  docker_file="Dockerfile")
```

Reading this in your score.py `init()` function:

```py
def init():

  global model

  with open('runtime_params.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    params = pickle.load(file)

  model = loadModel(params['model_name'])
```

Since your creating a new image config with this approach, you'll need to build the image and re-deploy the service.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I was actually able to get it running by passing in the model name and label as input to the run method... however this means the model is being loaded every time it is hit, where as on the init method it would load once. This did mean I was ble to us a single, static score.py. However, it is not good practice soI am going to generate it on the fly per model and move the model load to the init method instead