# How use a .bin file in blob storage to be loaded to a model?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, fasttext

I have a .bin file in a blob in Azure Blob Storage.

I would like to use it to give to fasttext to use a method.

I tried it:

```
fr_embedding_file_path = "cc_fr_300_bin/cc.fr.300.bin"
fr_embedding_file = client.get_blob_client(blob=fr_embedding_file_path)
fr_embedding_file = fr_embedding_file.download_blob()

fr_model = fasttext.load_model(fr_embedding_file)
```

I think I have to do something else after `fr_embedding_file = fr_embedding_file.download_blob()` but don't know what. The size of bin file is 7GB and comes from https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html

I have this message :

```
'TypeError: loadModel(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported: 1. (self: fasttext_pybind.fasttext, arg0: str) -> None
Invoked with: <fasttext_pybind.fasttext object at ...>, <azure.storage.blob._download.StorageStreamDownloader object at ...>'
```

What can I do ?

Comment: How does what you've tried fail? (Is there an error message you haven't included that might include more hints?) Can you download the file to a local volume before opening, so that the `fasttext_load_model()` method doesn't have to use a remote stream that it might not support?

Comment: I updated my post to see the error I have.

The file is called in a deployment script in Databricks with command %%write, to write the script and deploy a model to Azure Kubernetes Service. I can't call a local file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if given references help to work around:

As per the error  the arg0 (1st positional argument) should be a str(string).
fasttext.load_model accepts first argument as string or char and second argument is utf-8 encoding which is optional.

See if fasttext.load_model(str) can only load files from the local filesystem. Try to copy the data to the local filesystem and then load it from there, e.g.
Check this reference [from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68760682/error-loading-fasttext-model-in-gcp-dataflow-from-gcs-bucket).
Try to download blob to a file and load that file

```
blob.download_to_filename(local_model_file)
model_1 = fasttext.load_model(local_model_file)
```

Please see if you can use methods like content_as_bytes or content_as_text or stream from
[azure.storage.blob.StorageStreamDownloader class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.storagestreamdownloader?view=azure-python#methods)  and iterate through them or try make the argument to str () as in reference 1 .

Please check below **references** to work around :

1. [python 3.x - FastText: TypeError: loadModel(): incompatible function arguments - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096375/fasttext-typeerror-loadmodel-incompatible-function-arguments)
2. [Issue on azure sdk for python (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/10572)
3. [load model from bytes in memory · Issue  (github.com)](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/430)
4. [Azure Machine Learning Service - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58601697/how-to-pass-in-the-model-name-during-init-in-azure-machine-learning-service)

Comment: Thank you, I gave more memory to my Databricks cluster and now it works. So I think it was a memory issue